Fingerprint sensor stopped working
I've got a domain laptop (Dell L7340) that until earlier today was working perfectly with the built in fingerprint sensor. I installed a Synaptics Touchpad Firmware update through Dell Command and did a reboot, and now fingerprint unlocks and logins stopped working.
I suspect the firmware update is not related, however my organisation may have disabled something remotely by means of a policy update (as they have done this before), but until now I've always been able to reeneable it (through registry edits and whatnot).
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\AllowDomainPINLogon was set to 0, I've set that back to 1. PIN login (at least) is now confirmed to work again.
The fingerprint reader (as in, the hardware) appears to be confirmed to work properly in the device manager:

The Win10 Sign-in Options setting screen confirms fingerprint logon (as previously configured) is operational:

(being a domain laptop I have to adjust some settings through the registry, hence the warning message)
The Event Log seems to show the hardware is properly initiated:

The Windows Biometric Service successfully created a Biometric Unit
for sensor: Control Vault w/ Fingerprint Touch Sensor
(CVUSBDRV\CV3_WBF_PROVIDER_TOUCH\6&C3AC727&0&513)
The sensor's mode is "Advanced," its pool-type is "System," and it's
isolated in a "Local System" process.
See the "Details" pane for additional information about the sensor's
new configuration.

The new behaviour is that any touching of the fingerprint sensor is simply not detected, whether it is at the login screen, on the lock screen, or using Windows Hello Fingerprint (above) to add a new fingerprint.
As this laptop has operated with fingerprint authentication ever since I got it about half a year ago, I'm not inclined to suspect a hardware issue, and as the AllowDomainPINLogon setting was suddenly set to 0 tonight, I'm inclined to suspect it's a software change.
Are there any other registry keys or other settings that could cause this particular behaviour (everything appearing normal, except nothing responds to touching the fingerprint sensor)? In short, how do I get my fingerprint sensor to work properly again?
EDIT: digging further down the event log shows this:

The Windows Biometric Service failed to start its secure component.
The operation failed with error: 0x80070032.

The strange thing is that this message precedes the one above ("..successfully created a Biometric Unit for sensor: Control Vault w/ Fingerprint Touch Sensor...")... What's going on here?

Ask IT staff. It may very well have been disabled, since they're easily spoofed: https://www.srlabs.de/blog-post/spoofing-fingerprints

That would only be relevant if the device left my presence, which it doesn't (I am very careful with my electronics)... Gleaning credentials from having to type them in busy areas is a far bigger risk in my case. IT support is not particularly helpful beyond simple questions, so I'm trying to solve this on my own. If you have any suggestions on how to solve this, I'm happy to hear them :)

The solution on my Dell laptop was to reinstall the Dell Control Vault driver (basically reinstalling some drivers from the support website of your laptop brand should do the trick).
More details: a buggy windows update is the origin of the issue, see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-11-24h2#fingerprint-sensors-might-experience-problems-after-a-device-is-locked

The timing of that bug appearing suggests this was the problem, however I can't confirm reinstalling the Dell Control Vault driver works as somehow it disappeared on its own...

You can download Dell Control Vault on the Dell support website.
I had the issue, installed it, and it worked again just after restarting the laptop.

according to other forums, the device driver is signed with a certificate that expired on 26 - 27 september , depending on your timezone.
(C:\windows\system32\winBioplugins\ *.dll )

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
